# Basic Calculator for iOS Array Issues

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to make a simple calculator app for iOS. The program so far is supposed to take a float value (as a string) and store it in an array. then take an operator (stored as string) and store it in the next array spot, then another value ... The problem I am having is that when i loop through the array to check that the values are being input correctly I'm having the values replace with the latest input

i.e. i put in a 6+9 I get a 9+9 or 1+2-3 I get a 3+3-3 etc...

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, Please help.

Here is my code.

```
// BasicCalculatorViewController.m//


- (IBAction)numberButtonTouched:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIButton *currentButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSString *buttonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[currentButton currentTitle]];

    // ONLY ALLOWS ONE DECIMAL PLACE PERVALUE //
    if ([buttonString isEqualToString:@"."]) {
        NSRange range = [self.currentValueString rangeOfString:@"."];
        if (range.location == NSNotFound) {
            [self.currentValueString appendString:buttonString];
        }
    } else {
        [self.currentValueString appendString:buttonString];
    }

    [self.basicCalculator setNumberValue:self.currentValueString];
    [self updateUI];
}


- (IBAction)mainOperatorButtonTouched:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self.currentValueString setString:@""];
    UIButton *currentButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSString *buttonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[currentButton currentTitle]];

    [self.basicCalculator determineOperatorButtonPressed:buttonString];
    [self updateUI];
}

- (void) updateUI
{
    self.equationLabel.text = [self.basicCalculator getContentsOfEquation];
    self.resultsLabel.text = self.basicCalculator.total;
}



// BasicCalculator.m //


- (void) setNumberValue:(NSString *)stringValue
{
    NSLog(@"StringValue = %@", stringValue);
    self.equationArray[self.equationArrayCounter] = stringValue;
    self.selectedNumber = [stringValue floatValue];

    for (int i = 0; i < [self.equationArray count]; i++) {
        NSLog(@"equationArray %d: %@", i,self.equationArray[i]);

    }
    NSLog(@"\n");

}


- (void) determineOperatorButtonPressed:(NSString *)buttonLabel
{
    self.equationArrayCounter ++;

    if ([buttonLabel isEqualToString:@"+"]) [self.equationArray addObject:@"+"];
    if ([buttonLabel isEqualToString:@"−"]) [self.equationArray addObject:@"−"];
    if ([buttonLabel isEqualToString:@"×"]) [self.equationArray addObject:@"×"];
    if ([buttonLabel isEqualToString:@"÷"]) [self.equationArray addObject:@"÷"];
    if ([buttonLabel isEqualToString:@"="]) [self.equationArray addObject:@"="];

    self.equationArrayCounter++;
}


-(NSMutableString *)getContentsOfEquation
{
    NSMutableString *contents = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    for (NSString *value in self.equationArray) {
        [contents appendString:value];
    }
    return contents;
}




@end
```

Comment: It would help if you only show the code that is giving you the issue

Comment: Where are you incrementing `self.equationArrayCounter` when setting the number value. You'd probably be better to use [self.equationArray addObject: stringValue] this way the latest object will always go at the end of the array. (there's also `insertObjectAtIndex:` if you wanted to add things to the beginning of the array for instance).

Comment: Im using the equationArrayCounter variable so it updates on the fly only inserting an object a after a operator is entered i.e. the user enters 8 it does the math then a 9 the number is 89 is does the math... either way though i tried addObject and insertObject:AtIndex: after being suggested and it still changes all the value instead of just adding it to the end. Any more Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

REPLACE self.equationArray[self.equationArrayCounter] = stringValue; 
WITH    [equationArray addObject:stringValue]; 
IN      - (void) setNumberValue:(NSString *)stringValue

Maybe the index in which you are trying to deliver your object to is already occupied with the previous entry.